ansible: dynamic inventory: How to link libvirt VMs with custom groups?
I have used terraform to provision several VMs based on the Arch Linux cloud image. Here are the libvirt VMs by their name:

archlinux-x86-64-000
archlinux-x86-64-001
archlinux-x86-64-002
archlinux-x86-64-003
archlinux-x86-64-004

It is now not clear to me how I can label the VMs so that they can be assigned to corresponding inventory groups? The documentation of keyed_groups and the examples of the plugin is not very good
At the moment I would like to map the following inventory:
all: 
  hosts: 
    archlinux-x86-64-000: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-001: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-002: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-003: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-004: {}

archlinux:
  hosts: 
    archlinux-x86-64-000: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-001: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-002: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-003: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-004: {}

kubernetes: 
  children: 
    kubernetes_masters: {} 
    kubernetes_nodes: {}

kubernetes_masters: 
  hosts:
    archlinux-x86-64-000: {}

kubernetes_nodes: 
  hosts:
    archlinux-x86-64-001: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-002: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-003: {}
    archlinux-x86-64-004: {}

I've tried to use keyed_groups to group by archlinux via the following inventory configuration.
---
plugin: "community.libvirt.libvirt"
uri: 'qemu:///system'
keyed_groups:
- key: "archlinux"
  prefix: "archlinux"

But when I execute ping for the group archlinux, no hosts can be found: ansible --inventory libvirt-inventory.yml archlinux -m ping. When I output the inventory via ansible-inventory --inventory libvirt-inventory.yml --list, the hosts of the group all are listed, but my custom groups are not present.
Can someone explain to me how I can realize the assignment between VMs and groups with the plugin?
